# Getting error TypeError: Promise.any is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

I am learning Promise.any from the following site.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any
The IDE does not show any error, but while running using yarn command , I am getting the following error.

```
E:\typescript-2020-1\promise-usages-1\lib\basics1\promise-any.service.js:18                                                
        Promise.any([                                                                                                      
                ^                                                                                                                                                                              
TypeError: Promise.any is not a function                                                                                   
    at PromiseAnyService.validateAll_Type1 (E:\typescript-2020-1\promise-usages-1\lib\basics1\promise-any.service.js:18:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\typescript-2020-1\promise-usages-1\lib\test.js:35:7)                                         
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)                                                            
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)                                              
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)                                                                 
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)                                                       
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)                                    
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47                                                                              
 ERROR  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I have written the simple code to test. Please help where I am doing wrong in a Typescript class.

```
const promise1 = Promise.reject(0);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'quick'));
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'slow'));

const proms = [promise1, promise2, promise3];

Promise.any(proms).then((result) => console.log(result));
```

Currently I am using NodeJs 12 and Typescript 3.8.3

Comment: this feature is not yet available in the latest **stable** chrome. use chrome canary version and it will work fine

Comment: Sir, I am writing it as standalone program,

Comment: It means NodeJs 12 does not support Promise.any ?

Comment: not sure about node, but your browser surely doesn't. It seems this exact feature is very new

Comment: I am not using any browser, it is a simple standalone program where I run using Node.

Comment: Lol, oops! Mea culpa.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any#Browser_compatibility It's not supported by Node yet.

Comment: Sir, which version of Node Js supports `Promise.any`?

Comment: According to the MDN page - none. That's what you get for using brand new features.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answers, it means as of now Node Js 12 version does not support `Promise.any()`.

Comment: It's pretty simple to write your own polyfill for `Promise.any()` though you will (probably) also need to write your own `AggregateError` constructor.

Comment: I found an interesting alternatve here(https://forums.meteor.com/t/promise-any-is-not-a-function/54603/2). I myself haven't implemented it yet for my usecase. Posting it here incase it helps anyone.

Answer (score 11):

The method [Promise.any](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) was supported in node.js 15.0.0, your node.js version is old, so you could update it and try again.

Answer (score 4):

Imho it's better to stick with whatever is supported in your current setup, and it seems like esnext.promise is not there yet, but:

I'm in a situation where I'm porting a sizeable live codebase away from Bluebird, and this npm module did it for me (I'm on node v12.12.0):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.any